# Python. QtDesigner Widgets Labels que aparecen sólo en medio del form

Tags: python

Quiero colocar los distintos widgets en el form y me encuentro con que si coloco los widgets antes de Layout, sí los puedo colocar en el sitio que desee, pero si pongo primero el layout -> Layout in a Grid, se colocan en la linea central del form, pegado a la izquierda y no los puedo recolocar, siempre vuelven a la linea central pegado a la izqda.He mirado las Properties y no veo cómo podría modificar esto. ¿Qué puedo hacer? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que he dado con la solución. Poniéndome sobre el widget en Inspector de objetos pinchamos y nos aparece un menú. Una de las opciones presentadas es "Alineación de la distribución" y aquí se nos presentan las opciones de alineación dcha/izda arriba/abajo sí/no. Hlgo.